# Trying to add promo code functionality to paypal transaction

Tags: javascript, php, html, paypal

I've looked everywhere and sifted through the paypal api but my downfall as a developer is when I look at code that isn't my own, I'm looking at a bunch of hieroglyphics that have absolutely no resonance with me. I've been given the task of adding promo code functionality to a site I had no hand in building

I made some progress on my own from looking at an [online example](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Selling-on-your-website/How-can-I-put-promotional-discount-codes-on-my-checkout/td-p/646016?profile.language=en-gb) so it shouldn't require a bunch of assistance, the live site is http://alphafreakapparel.com/viewcart.php[1](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Selling-on-your-website/How-can-I-put-promotional-discount-codes-on-my-checkout/td-p/646016?profile.language=en-gb) . I have an item in the cart and I enter the promo code which is ALPHAPENCE15 and i get just one console error. The code I added is this script in the head of the html doc

```
<script language = "javascript">
<!--
function validate(text1,text2) {
var text1;

if (text1 == text2)
 {
 window.alert("15% discount applied!");
 data.cart_total.toFixed(2) = data.cart_total.toFixed(2) * 0.15;
 }
if (text1 !== text2)
 {
 window.alert("Incorrect code");
 }
}

function CalculateOrder(form) {

 if (form.text1.value == "ALPHAPENCE15")
 {
 form.discount_rate.value = "15";
 form.discount_rate2.value = "15";
 form.on3.value = "Coupon Entered";
 form.os3.value = "ALPHAPENCE15";
 }
}
//-->
</script>
```

and this code to prompt the code

```
<!-- Start Coupon Validate -->  
Enter Promo Code:
   <input type="text" name="text1">
   <input type="button" value="Check" name="Submit" onclick=javascript&colon;validate(text1.value,"ALPHAPENCE15") >
<!-- End Coupon Validate -->
```

the error i got was
Uncaught ReferenceError: text1 is not defined     viewcart.php:78onclick
What do you think is causing it? I added the var text1; just for that reason.

Also note, I'm not sure if this was the correct way to do this, but to apply the 15% off, I just put *0.15 in the if statement in the head script so that when the if statement completes, it adjusts the total.

Comment: I don't do much with JavaScript, but I'd say because you have `var text1` and you aren't setting it to anything, like `var text1 = text1`. As I said, I don't do much with this. Do you even need to do `var text1` since you are passing it in through the function? Also, if you multiply it *.15 and set it to that, you are charging them ONLY 15%, not taking 15% off. I would do `data.cart_total.toFixed(2) - (data.cart_total.toFixed(2) * .15)`

Comment: I am looking at your 2nd piece of code now. Should the `onclick=javascript&colon;validate(text1.value,"ALPHAPENCE15")` not have quotes? `onclick="javascript&colon;validate(text1.value,"ALPHAPENCE15")"` and can you take the value of `text1` that easily?

Comment: I would say instead of using `text1.value` use `document.getElementsByName("text1")[0].value;` and try that

Comment: @TheNytangel I applied all of your recommendations and there was definitely a lot of progress achieved by that. Now when the quotes are around the onClick attribute, console reports "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } " which is weird because when i ctrl+f to find all }, they all are complete pairs of {}. I added a reload snippet to both success and fail if statements of the validate function, which doesn't trigger with the quotes around the onclick.

Comment: @TheNytangel but I tried it without quotes and it actually reloaded, but the promo code always fails validation even if it is the correct code. very strange. But at least it knows what text1 is now!